# Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname for two domain names

Tags: zend-framework, bootstrapping, zend-controller-router

```
protected function _initHostnameRouter()
{
    $this->bootstrap('autoload');
    $this->bootstrap('FrontController');

    $front = $this->getResource('FrontController');

    $router = $front->getRouter();

    $hostRoute1 = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname('admin.example.net',array('module' => 'admin'));
    $hostRoute2 = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname('vouchers.example.net',array('module' => 'vouchers'));
    $pathRoute = new Curo_Route_NoModule();

    $router->removeDefaultRoutes();
    $router->addRoute('default',     $pathRoute);
    $router->addRoute('admin',       $hostRoute1->chain($pathRoute));
    $router->addRoute('vouchers',    $hostRoute2->chain($pathRoute));
}
```

I have the above code used in Bootstrap file and it is working good. I need to add another domain name for admin module. Now I am using `admin.example.net` for admin module. I also need to add `admin.examplenew.net`. I don't need to change the old domain. Both should be working at the same time.

I have tried,

```
    $hostRoute1 = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname('admin.example.net',array('module' => 'admin'));
    $hostRoute2 = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname('vouchers.example.net',array('module' => 'vouchers'));
    $hostRoute3 = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname('admin.examplenew.net',array('module' => 'adminnew'));
    $pathRoute = new Curo_Route_NoModule();

    $router->removeDefaultRoutes();
    $router->addRoute('default',     $pathRoute);
    $router->addRoute('admin',       $hostRoute1->chain($pathRoute));
    $router->addRoute('vouchers',    $hostRoute2->chain($pathRoute));
    $router->addRoute('adminnew',    $hostRoute3->chain($pathRoute));
```

But both domain names are not working at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding `$hostRoute1` and `$hostRoute3` to the `$router` under the same name: `admin`. So the second assignment is overriding the first.

Make the keys unique - by, say, changing the last one to `adminnew` - and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I need to create a new module name for the admin module(like adminnew), don't I? Can't I refer to the same module name for different domains?

Comment: No need to change the module name; you can route the two different domains to the same module. The issue above is that you are attempting to add two distinct routes with the same *route name* `admin` to the router. If you change the name of the second route, then the router will be able to retain them both.